# How to style Swiper in MUI

Tags: material-ui, swiper.js

I am using Swiper in MUI and I am having trouble applying styling to "active" or "next"/"previous" slides. We aren't using a global css file for styling but MUI's theme based styling. I have been able to target some things like pagination bullets inline, but I am unable to target things like active slide. So this works...

```
<Swiper
        style={{
          // '--swiper-navigation-color': '#fff',
          '--swiper-pagination-color': 'red',
          '--swiper-pagination-bullet-inactive-color': 'black',
          '--swiper-pagination-bullet-inactive-opacity': '100%',
        }}
```

However when I try to add in something like

```
'--swiper-slide-active-opacity': '10%',
```

It isn't successfully applying the style. Normally something like this inside of an sx={{}} would work

```
'& .swiper-slide-active': {opacity:'10%'},
```

but since Swiper isn't an mui component I don't have that option. Do I need to style swiper in my theme? If so, can I get a quick example of that syntax? All of the examples I can find use standard CSS for styling.

I have also tried setting the effect to 'creative' and still get no effect.

```
effect: 'creative',
creativeEffect: {
    prev: {
       opacity: "10%",
    },
    next: {
       opacity: "10%",
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest if you prefer to use the `sx` MUI property you can wrap your `Swipper` component in a MUI component and then target it from there using the css selectors like you would write css using nesting. Another way would be to use styled components if you want to avoid writing in the stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

So, I was able to get the native swiper "effect='creative'" method to work. I had neglected to import and apply all of the appropriate modules.

```
import 'swiper/css/effect-creative';
...
<Swiper
  grabCursor={true}
  effect="creative"
  creativeEffect={{
    prev: {
      translate: ['-100%', 0, 0],
      opacity: 0.4,
          },
    next: {
      translate: ['111%', 0, 0],
      opacity: 0.4,
          },
  }}
...
modules={[Navigation, Pagination, A11y, EffectCreative]}
```

Still a little limited as to what kinds of styling can get applied to the next and previous slides using Swiper's built in styling system, but a few functions later and I should get my desired result.